# Encode Swift array for Alamofire post using URLEncoding

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Reposting as I messed up with the type of encoding before... 
I need to send an array to the server with Alamofire using URLEncoding. However, it needs to be encoded in some way for Alamofire to send it properly. This is my code:

```
let parameters: [String : Any] = [
    "names" : ["bob", "fred"]
]

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
   .responseJSON { response in
       // etc
   }
```

However the parameters never get encoded and just get sent as nil. How can I encode it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by using the following custom encoding:

```
struct ArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var request = try URLEncoding().encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
        request.url = URL(string: request.url!.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "%5B%5D=", with: "="))
        return request
    }
}
```

The problem was the arrays were being encoded like `foo[]=bar&foo[]=bar2` whereas my server needed it to look like `foo=bar&foo=bar2`. `ArrayEncoding()` then replaces `URLEncoding.default` in the request.

Comment: Your answer could be improved using Rômulo Diniz's suggestion. No need to do string replacements anymore!

Answer (score 7):

As of now you can use for this & issue on parameters:

```
let enc = URLEncoding(arrayEncoding: .noBrackets)
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: enc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope it will work for you. In this code the array is being encoded with NSJSONSerialization :

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let values = ["06786984572365", "06644857247565", "06649998782227"]

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)

Alamofire.request(request)
.responseJSON { response in
    // do whatever you want here
    switch response.result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

        if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(responseString)
        }
    case .success(let responseObject):
        print(responseObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code before from another Stackoverflow post, it didn't work. I think it's because it sets the values in the body of the request but I want it encoded in the URL like ?names=bob&names=fred

Comment: I don't think then encoding is the issue, there must be some other issue. Or maybe the issue can be from server side.

Answer (score 0):

This also effects Twilio's POST body for multiple MediaUrl values. Thanks so much for your original, here's a "body" version for POST params...

https://gist.github.com/lacyrhoades/4d1e2a4979838901fbe042653714250b

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLEncoding.default for .get httpMethod, and JSONEncoding.default for other httpMethods ex: .post, .delete, .put

```
AF.request( url,
            method: httpMethod ,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: httpMethod == .get ? URLEncoding.default : JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: headers )
    .responseJSON(completionHandler: {})
```

Also, you can set httpHeaders content type based on httpMethod as the following code:

```
    enum RequestContentType: String {
        case json = "application/json"
        case urlEncoded  = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        case multipart = "multipart/form-data"
    }
                
    let headers :HTTPHeaders  = [ 
                "Content-Type" : httpMethod == .get ? contentType : RequestContentType.json.rawValue 
// add other parameters here ...
            ]
```